# C programming Scrabble type

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to figure out how to test two strings together to see if the letters in an array named "target" is contained within array "str1". If all letters in target can be found in str1, then testWord returns true, otherwise, it returns false. This is the code I have so far, which stops after finding one letter. How do I keep looping through the rest of str1?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int testWord(char str1[], char target[]);

int main() {
    char str1 [8] = {'q','i','j','i','b','o'};
    char target [3] = {'j','i','b'};
    int a= testWord(str1, target);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}

int testWord(char str1[], char target[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*str1) ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(*target); j++) {
            if (strstr(str1, target)) {
                printf("%s%c%s\n","Target letter ", target[i], " was found");
                //delete letter from set
                str1[i - 1] = str1[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code  in a human readable way? FOr instance add spaces around operators consistently, indent the code consistently etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your code,

1. You initialize the arrays correctly, but they are not [c](/questions/tagged/c) strings. To make them valid strings in the sense of [c](/questions/tagged/c) you need to `nul` terminate them,

   ```
   char str1[8]   = {'q', 'i', 'j', 'i', 'b', 'o', '\0'};
   /*                                                ^ nul */
   char target[3] = {'j', 'i', 'b', '\0'};
   /*                                 ^ nul */
   ```
2. You used the `sizeof` operator wrong

   ```
   sizeof(*str1)
   ```

   will always give you `1` because the type of `str1` is `char *` hence the type of `*str1` is `char` and `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`.

   Read about the `sizeof` operator, it doesn't return the length of the string, it evaluates the parameter at compile time and it gives the size of the type or the size of the array in the case of an array. Yours is not an array, even if you specify the size in the parameter definition it will be converted to a pointer of type `char *`.

These are only two errors, but they are many errors for such a little amount of code.